# Two exceptions "at the same time", what is the proper way to handle this situation?

Tags: scala, exception, try-catch

I have a situation where I need to call to `foo` method, if it fails call `bar` method, then re-throw the original exception (wrapped).

My problem is that `bar` method could fail too, and its exception information is important too.

When I create a new Exception there only one cause, and I have two. I could create something like `class MyException(cause1, cause2) extends RuntimeException(cause1)` but `cause2` will be out of the standard mechanisms that exceptions have (stacktrace, etc).

Is there a better way to handle this situation?

The following code is a simplified example.

```
// I can't change this code
def foo:String = throw new FooException("foo method fails")
def bar:String = throw new BarException("bar method fails")

// my code
try {
  foo
} catch {
  case error1:FooException =>
    try {
      // if foo fails, I want to call bar
      bar
      throw new MyException("my exception", error1)
    } catch {
      case error2:BarException =>
        // but bar could fail too
        throw new MyException("my exception", ???)
        // if my cause is error1, I lost error2 information (message and stack)
        // if my cause is error2, I lost error1 information (message and stack)
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What should happen if `bar` succeeds? Should the returned `String` be discarded in favor of throwing the `foo` error? Is `bar` being invoked just for a side-effect?

Comment: yes, `bar` is an insert into a DB, in this case its return is discarded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pack your `MyException` throwable with one or both of the "suppressed" exceptions.

```
val myEx = new MyException("my exception")
myEx.addSuppressed(error1)
myEx.addSuppressed(error2)
throw myEx
```

Then it's up to the catching code to unpack it.

```
case err : MyException =>
  val arr :Array[Throwable] = err.getSuppressed
  // arr contains all the "suppressed" exceptions that were added,
  // stack traces and all
```

---

Still, it's arguably better to express the possibility of error in the type system rather than leave it to the (perhaps nonexistent) catching code to do the right thing.

```
import util.Try

val res :Either[List[Throwable],String] =
  Try(foo).fold(fErr =>
    Try(bar).fold(bErr => Left(fErr::bErr::Nil), _ => Left(fErr::Nil))
  , Right(_))
```

From there you can proceed as needed.

```
res match {
  case Right(s)  => println(s)  //foo result string
  case Left(lst) =>
    println(lst.map(_.getMessage()).mkString(",")) //foo method fails,bar method fails
    lst.foreach(_.printStackTrace())               //both stack traces
}
```

Comment: So, your suggestion is to return an Either rather than throwing an exception?